# Extend Google Maps behind transparent header and sidebar

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We are building a website which should have the following layout:

[image]

As you can see, there's a header and a sidebar, and the content area is a Google Map built with the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Now we would like to make the header and the sidebar half-transparent, such that the map would be visible behind the header and the sidebar, something like this:

[image]

However, now the header and the sidebar are overlapping the Google logo and the zoom control.

Is there a way to tell the Google map that it should apply some padding to the placement of its controls?

Of course we could try to move the Google logo and the controls "manually" by applying some CSS, but the Google Maps Javascript API would restore their location every time the user uses the map (e.g. on panning or scrolling), so this would result in a fight between our code and Google's.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer that seems to work reliably:

## The controls

You can add a top-margin to the controls by adding a dummy control:

```
var dummy = document.createElement('div');
dummy.style.height = '55px';
dummy.style.width = '100px';
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(dummy);
```

Then, in the configuration, place the zoom control with `RIGHT_TOP`:

```
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
},
```

Note that this only works because `TOP_RIGHT` controls are always placed *above* `RIGHT_TOP` controls.

## The Google logo

The following code waits for the Google map to be initialized, then adds the class `gmaps-logo-padded` to the logo:

```
var moveLogo = function () {
    var logo = $('#map div a div img').parent().parent().parent();
    if (logo.length == 0)
        window.setTimeout(moveLogo, 10);
    else
        logo.addClass('gmaps-logo-padded');
};
moveLogo();
```

Then, by applying the following CSS, you can change the placement of the logo:

```
.gmaps-logo-padded {
    left: 300px !important;
}
```

Please note that paragraph 9.4 of the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) forbid hiding or removing the logo.

Answer (score 1):

As for the `zoom control` placement, you can use [Control positioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlPositioning), for example:

```
zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
    },
```

Comment: Yes but if I place it with `RIGHT_TOP`, the header overlaps it. I want it to be placed with a top-margin of at least the header height, so it is placed *below* the header. Note that the zoom control in the screenshot above is already positioned with `RIGHT_TOP`.